# How to connect web api via volley in android

Tags: android, asp.net-web-api, android-volley

I have a wep api like bellow

```
[HttpPost]
        public dynamic GetData(string sp, Dictionary<string, dynamic> dict, string db)
        {
            Dictionary<string, dynamic> defultdr = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>();
            if (dict != null)
            {
                defultdr = dict;
            }
            System.Data.DataTable dt = DAL.GetDataTableFromStoredProc(sp, defultdr, System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.
ConnectionStrings[db].ConnectionString);

            return Request.CreateResponse<System.Data.DataTable>(HttpStatusCode.OK, dt);
        }
```

in android 
Application File

```
public class Tapplication extends Application {
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private static Tapplication mInstance;
    public static final String TAG = Tapplication.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final int MY_SOCKET_TIMEOUT_MS = 120000;
    private static Context mContext;

    @Override

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();


        mInstance = this;
        mContext = getApplicationContext();

    }

    public static Context getContext() {
        return mContext;
    }

    public static synchronized Tapplication getInstance() {

        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

        }

        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
        // set the default tag if tag is empty
        req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {

//        req.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(MY_SOCKET_TIMEOUT_MS, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
//                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        req.setTag(TAG);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
        if (mRequestQueue != null) {
            mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
        }
    }

}
```

When i am calling

```
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            Map<String, String> mp = new HashMap();
            mp.put("@id", ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_login_user)).getText().toString());
            mp.put("@pass", ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.edi_login_password)).getText().toString());
            json.put("db", getString(R.string.DB_SCM));
            json.put("sp","test_api");
            json.put("dict", null);
           //json.put("dict", mp);
            Tapplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(new JsonObjectRequest(Method.POST, getString(R.string.api_v1_get_data), json, loginListener(), genericErrorListener()));
```

> E/Volley: [144] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code
>   404 for http://some.webapi.com:8095/api/v1/TService/GetData/

it is working on **POSTMAN** but it is not working on android.

what to do ? what i am missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making a model in web api solved problem.